# Add a listener to datatables cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to add a checkbox and a listener to every cell in 7th column of a table (I use datatables):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // add checkbox to scheduled
    $("#pm_table td:nth-child(7)").each(function() {
        var site_id =2;
        // $(this).closest("tr");
        // add checkbox
        $(this).prepend('<input type="checkbox" '+(($(this).text())!='0'?'checked':' ')
        +
        // add listener
        ' onchange = alert("site_id:" ' + site_id + '") '
        +
        '/>');
    });
});

</script>
```

the problem is when I try to check/uncheck the checkbox, I encounter this error:

> (index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

what am I doing wrong, also is there a better way to add a listener to a cell using datatables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is due to the lack of quotes around your `onchange` event attribute, however you should really avoid using them at all and use a delegated event handler. Try this:

```
$("#pm_table td:nth-child(7)").each(function() {
    var $checkbox = $('<input type="checkbox" class="foo" />').appendTo(this);
    $checkbox.prop('checked', parseInt($(this).text(), 10) != 0);
});

$('#pm_table').on('change', '.foo', function() {
    var site_id = 2;
    alert(site_id);
})
```

Comment: so the listener is set for any change of the table? how do I set it for changes of the 7th column only?

Comment: No, the listener is only on the `.foo` checkbox elements that you append

Comment: Thanks! If I understand correctly $(this) inside the delegation is the table? Then how can I get the text in neighboring cell to the left of the checkbox?

Comment: Nope, in the delegated event handler `this` would be the checkbox. To get the previous cell, use `$(this).closest('td').prev('td')`

Answer (score 1):

Your adding extra `+,"` in onchange event .I was applied with one example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        // add checkbox to scheduled
        $("#three").each(function() {
            var site_id =2// $(this).closest("tr");
            // add checkbox
            $(this).prepend('<input type="checkbox" '+(($(this).text())!='0'?'checked':' ')
                +
                // add listener
                ' onchange = alert("site_id:'+site_id+'") />');
        });

    } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="three">1212</div>
```